# Como usar required em select em formulario validado por jqBootstrapValidation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formulário, validação, jquery-validate

Estou utilizando a biblioteca **jqBootstrapValidation** para validar formulários junto com as propriedades `required` e  `data-validation-required-message` (exibe uma mensagem de erro customizada).

Está tudo funcionando corretamente mas quando eu utilizo um elemento `select` ele não funciona mesmo se o valor no campo não for selecionado, ele não valida permitindo o usuário enviar o valor padrão, ex: Selecione.

Comment: Fernando, você poderia colocar um exemplo do problema? você pode usar jsfiddle ou a propria ferramenta do stackoverflow para colocar o código.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que alterar o valor do **option** para vazio (`value=""`).

**Exemplo funcional**

```js
$(function() {

  $("input,textarea,select").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      alert("OK");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/jQuery-1.7.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>

<!-- Formulário -->

<form novalidate>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Estado:</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="cbEstado" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, selecione um estado." required>
        <option value="">-- selecione um item --</option>
        <option value="saopaulo">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="riodejaneiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Fonte: [Validate that a select field has been set](https://github.com/ReactiveRaven/jqBootstrapValidation/issues/10)